# Reducing Kakutani's fixed-point theorem to Brouwer's using a selection theorem

Tags: proof-verification, fixed-point-theorems

[Kakutani's fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) is quite similar to [Brouwer's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed_point_theorem) - the main difference is that Brouwer speaks about single-valued functions and Brouwer about multi-valued functions.

There is a way to go from multi-valued functions to single-valued ones - it is [Michael's selection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_selection_theorem). So, I thought of the following simple proof to Kakutani's theorem:

1. Given a multi-valued function $F$ satisfying Kakutani's conditions [$F$ has closed graph, $F(x)$ is nonempty and convex for all $x$], by Michael's selection theorem, there is a continuous single-valued selection-function $f$, such that $f(x)\in F(x)$ for all $x$.
2. By Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, the continuous function $f$ has a fixed-point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$.
3. Since $f$ is a selection function, $x_0\in F(x_0)$, so it is a fixed point of $F$ too.

The main thing I am not sure about is all the conditions of the theorems. Particularly, Michael's selection theorem requires that, if $F$ is a function from $X$ to $2^Y$, then:

- $X$ is a paracompact space;
- $Y$ is a Banach space;
- $F$ is lower hemicontinuous;
- For all $x \in X$, the set $F(x)$ is nonempty, convex and closed.

I read the definitions of these concepts, but I am still not sure whether they fit exactly the requirements of Kakutani's theorem.

MY QUESTION: is the proof I wrote above correct? If not, can it be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Michael's selection theorem will **not** generally apply to a function satisfying the conditions of Kakutani's fixed point theorem. In particular, though the other three conditions will always be satisfied, the condition that $F$ is lower hemicontinuous might fail. An example where this fails (adapted from [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem#A_function_that_does_not_satisfy_convexity) on the wikipedia page) is the function $F : [0, 1] \to 2^{[0, 1]}$ for which
$$F(x) = \begin{cases} \{1\} & x < 1/2 \\ [0, 1] & x = 1/2 \\ \{0\} & x > 1/2 \end{cases}$$
Kakutani's theorem guarantees that this function has a fixed point, but Michael's selection theorem does not apply -- indeed, you can check that $F$ has no continuous selection function. To me, this suggests there isn't a way to fix your proof.